# Shape keys & multiresolution, good or bad idea?

Tags: shape-keys, multiresolution

I've happily started learning Blender recently, and soon will want to start animating stuff.

It's been my understanding that the multiresolution modifier is a good way of adding more detail to your meshes.

It's also been my understanding that Shape keys are a good way of animating complex/subtle animations that are hard to do with bones.

When googling around i find some posts (i presume outdated) that suggest these two methods are incompatible with each other (examples: [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/sculpt-shape-keys-and-multires/504826), [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/suggested-workarounds-for-using-shape-keys-with-multires/442875),[here](https://forums.cgsociety.org/t/how-do-i-animate-using-shape-keys-on-a-multirez-sculpted-model/1061428) and [here](https://polycount.com/discussion/215405/blender-shape-keys-and-multi-res-modifier)). However, when experimenting around i find that when applying shape keys to the base mesh, blender seems to interpolate the position of all the higher resolution vertices based on the position of vertices in the base mesh, thus shaping the overall shape without losing the details stored within the multiresolution.

So my question is: Is this still a bad idea? and if so, why?

I am aware that one can bake the normals of the multiresolution model onto the base mesh, but then i would have to figure out how to correctly combine these with my procedurally generated bump map.

Comment: Hi Arne, welcome to Blender.SE, this is a good question with sufficient research. Since you empirically discovered, that you can combine both toolsets, it would be nice if you could add a link or quote from some of the posts you mention.

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, Blender nowadays (from on 2.9 perhaps) supports combining shapekeys and multiresolution modifier. Before, modifying base mesh completely mangled multires data.